# Fetch API : is there a way to display sended data from POST request?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm using Fetch API in service worker.

```
 self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
    if(e.request.method === 'POST') {
        console.log(e.request)
    }
 }
```

Is there a way to get sended data ( payload ) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found:

```
e.request.text().then((bodyAsText) => {
    console.log(bodyAsText);
  });
```